# How do I use a template engine (mustache, handlebars) in Zend framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework, handlebars.js

I want to render my handlebars templates with a layout. I'm trying to write my own View from Zend_View_Abstract class loosely based upon a few tutorials I come across for Smarty/ZF1. Don't know if I'm going about it the correct way, must be a simpler way (controller method, helper etc). Anyway I'll post what I have:

```
<?php

use Handlebars\Handlebars;  

class Handlebars_View extends Zend_View_Abstract
{
    private $engine = false;

    public function __construct($data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($data);

        $this->engine = new Handlebars;
    }

    public function assign($spec, $value=null)
    {

    }

    public function escape($var)
    {
        if (is_string($var))
        {
            return parent::escape($var);
        }
        elseif (is_array($var))
        {
            foreach ($var as $key => $val)
            {
                $var[$key] = $this->escape($val);
            }

            return $var;
        }
        else
        {
            return $var;
        }
    }

    public function render($name)
    { 
        // this will get me /var/www/shared-views-zf/application/views/scripts/
        // I don't know how to get the rest of the path e.g. 'users/login.phtml'
        //$viewScriptsPath = $this->getAllPaths()['scripts'][1]; // incomplete
        //$viewScriptsPath.= $viewNameFromSomewhere; // ??
        //$template = file_get_contents($viewScriptsPath); can't do this yet

        // get data which was pre assigned
        //$data = 

        // 
        //$content = $this->engine->render($template, $data)

        // i can set the layout content here (but how do I get the content)
        $this->layout()->content = 'Heloo';

        // getlayout full path
        require $this->getScriptPath($name); // require /var/www/shared-views-zf/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml
    }

    public function _run() {


    }
}
```

Clearly my render function is missing parts but hopefully it can be seen the direction I was trying to go. Also, I have the following in my bootstrap:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initViews()
    {
        $view = new Handlebars_View();
        $viewRender = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
            'ViewRenderer'
        );
        $viewRender->setView($view);
        $viewRender->setViewSuffix('phtml');
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRender);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

OK, I know I'm probably going about this the completely wrong way. In it's simplest form, youu implement handlebars in such a way:

```
use Handlebars\Handlebars;

$engine = new Handlebars;

$template = file_get_contents($filePath);

$result = $engine->render(
    $template,
    $data
);
```

.. but as can be seen I need to have access to $filePath (view script file), $data (array that gets passed to the view from the controller), then I could set from my View class the layout as such:

```
$this->layout()->content = $result;
require $layoutPath;
```

I would really appreciate if someone could explain the way this should be done. I'm not really getting anywhere with the docs or reading tutorials online. Also, I'm kinda stuck with ZF1 as it's what most of our applications are written in. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested but will get you there or very close).

In the render function:

```
public function render($name)
{ 
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // optional if you want to fallback to phtml
    if ($ext === 'hbs') {
        // get data which was assigned at controller level
        $data = $this->getVars();
        // it may get mad at this part!
        $template = file_get_contents($this->getScriptPath($name));
        // render
        $res = $this->engine->render($template, $data);
    } else {
        $res = parent::render($name);
    }
    return $res;
}
```